# Save data through ajax jQuery post with form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form and I want to save data through ajax jQuery post. If the save button is `type="submit"`, it does not do any this just empty alert... I want to save data and remain on same form with refresh fields...

Here is what I have tried:

```
$("#saveNewContact").click(function () {
  var name       = $("#name").val(); 
  var last_name  = $("#last_name").val();
  $.post("ajax_files/save_mydeals.php", {name: name, last_name: last_name},
   success: function(msg){ 
     alert(msg);
  });
 });
```

and here is my form

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
<table id="table_1" class="form_table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr><td>
    <input  name="name"  id="name" value="" tabindex="5" readonly="" type="text">
    <input  name="name"  id="name" value="" tabindex="5" readonly="" type="text"> 
    <button type="submit" id="update" style="display:none;" 
     class="save_button saveHEX" name="Update" 
     value="Update Listing">Save Lead</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: why don't you just set the input type as `button` ?

Comment: i want to clear form after this,empty text fields

Comment: you can clear it another way. `$('#myForm').find('input').val('');` do it inside your success function.

Comment: mplungjan:yes i have this $(function() {...}) and button is submit

Comment: can i use any validate,or beforsubmit etc etc?

Comment: How can you submit the form using an invisible submit button? Or are you showing it once they fill something in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do it this way

HTML

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
 <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Your jQuery

```
$("#update").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val(); 
  var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
  var dataString = 'name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'insert.php',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

So in the `insert.php` page

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $insert = "insert into TABLE_NAME values('$name','$last_name')";// Do Your Insert Query
  if(mysql_query($insert)) {
   echo "Success";
  } else {
   echo "Cannot Insert";
  }
?>
```

Hope this gives an Idea

Comment: exactly i tried this ..but issue was when button type was submit,it return empty alert...no data inserted in db...can i change type=submit?

Comment: @Methew : Yes You can use type="submit". But with a little modification.I have updated  the answer please check

Comment: I think it would be nicer to use the dataType attribute of the post (or ajax method -> set it to json and no need for ugly serialization !
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 9):

You do not need click event for this remove `$("#saveNewContact").click(function () {` and use `.submit()` jQuery method.

Also use .serialize that allow you to serialize form fields with value and create urlencoded dataString.

```
$("#myForm").on("submit",function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'post',
        url:'receiver url',
        data:formData,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            launchpreloader();
        },
        complete:function()
        {
            stopPreloader();
        },
        success:function(result)
        {
             alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind the form's submit instead AND no success in the $.post necessary, the function is enough:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal submission
    var name       = $("#name").val(); 
    var last_name  = $("#last_name").val();
    $.post("ajax_files/save_mydeals.php", {name: name, last_name: last_name},
     function(msg){ 
       alert(msg);
       $("#name").empty(); 
       $("#last_name").empty();
    });
   });
 });
```