# print name from form input saved to database dynamically

Tags: php, database, forms, dynamic, printing

hi thanks for clicking this post,

this might be a simple php problem - i want to make a minimalist 
add name to a website via php.

(type name) submit  ----> daniel

which ever the user enters in the form will print and be saved dynamically so the user can refresh the page etc but still see what they typed.

any help would mean a lot!

username@:

already works just need help saving to database or saved by IP address

Comment: What help do you want ? Do you want us to write whole code for you ?

Comment: do you have a database?

Comment: Better yet similar question: How do you make money without having to work?

Comment: <form action="#" method="get">
  name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  
  <btn input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: You should use AJAX to achieve this

Comment: is this similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308017/save-data-through-ajax-jquery-post-with-form-submit

Comment: shrivastava http://codepen.io/NickersF/pen/EVjVNd? this all works how i would write the ajax to save dynamically