# How to make an area of a page visible based on filling in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I need to validate and save data from an HTML form and then release a "piece" of my page.

I explain: I sell some products on the internet and I need to do lead capture. On my landing page I will only display the purchase button and the price of the product if the guy fills in Name, Email and Telephone ... do they work?

In other words, the future customer will see the whole page, but at the price point of the product, I display a form for him to fill out. If it is filled out, when clicking on the submit button, I display the area of the page that has a buy button.

The capture of the form data can even be a Google Forms form it doesn't even need freshness.

Obs. I'm super rusty in HTML. I believe I need to use jQuery for this, right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, although it might help with saving the form data. Here are the basic mechanics of showing a `<div>` after the user submits the form:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('price').style.display='block'; return false;">
   ...put your form here...
   <button type="submit">See price</button>
</form>
```

Then the section with price info:

```
<div id="price" style="display: none;">
   ...put your pricing info here...
</div>
```

The idea is that the `<div>` with pricing info starts out hidden (`display: none`). When the `<form>` is submitted, it changes the price's `display` attribute to `block` so it shows on the page.

This doesn't address capturing the form data, but you could pretty easily [do that with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308017/save-data-through-ajax-jquery-post-with-form-submit). jQuery would certainly make that easier. You'd need something on the back end to save it, unless you used something like Google Forms to redirect to another page with the prices after the user submits the Google form.

Comment: Hi. thanks very much, with this I already to know the start path to develop my soluction. Thanks